# How to generate server Api key from console developer to use finding distance of two locations

Tags: android, server, google-api, google-distancematrix-api

Actually I want to find distance between two location using Google direction api key. For that I need server key not app key but I am trying to build but its giving me app api which is cause of this error

```
"error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.
```

I don't know how to generate server api key. Please guide me how can I generate server key.

Here where I need server key:
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Vancouver+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=Server_key

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup)

Comment: yes................